# Android: block options menu while collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I have collapsing toolbar with options menu in fragment. When I collapse my toolbar, menu move above status bar. So, after collapse, I doesn't see 
menu options. I show it in screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Here my .xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/abl_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ctl_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_avatar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_main_logo"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_profile_avatar_background"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <include layout="@layout/component_transparent_toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_results"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_avatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_photo_camera_black_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/abl_toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

<include layout="@layout/component_profile_avatar_bottom_sheet" />
```

Here my code from fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mAdapter = new ProfileRVAdapter();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, parent, false);

    mIVAvatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);

    RecyclerView rvResults = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_results);
    rvResults.setLayoutManager(manager);
    rvResults.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.activity_main_profile_label);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        toolbar.setPadding(0, mActivity.getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
        toolbar.getLayoutParams().height = toolbar.getLayoutParams().height + mActivity.getStatusBarHeight();
    }

    mActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_avatar).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_gallery).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_photo).setOnClickListener(this);

    mBottomSheet = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.findViewById(R.id.ll_bottom_sheet));
    mBottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_edit:
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_logout:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any idea why it has happened?

**Edited / SOLVED:**
I solved my problem. Mistake was in toolbar attributes, I forgot app:layout_collapseMode="pin".

Comment: I don't see anything "over" the status bar. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: My options menu, that was in first screenshot, disappeared when i collapse toolbar - second screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Set design code of `Toolbar` in `layout.xml` code in `Activity's layout` file &
set toolbar as below in `Activity` Code,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

// Add this line of code in Activity file.

Comment: I can't move toolbar in activity xml file. As you can see, screen has bottom navigation view. Activity realise two fragments with fully different toolbars and functionality. So i can inflate toolbar only in fragment